# Erro ao gerar um PDF pelo PHP

Tags: php

Estou tendo um problema para gerar pdf, mas está dando este erro:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mdpf in C:\xampp\htdocs\devweb\sistemas\painel\gerar-pdf.php on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function WriteHTML() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\devweb\sistemas\painel\gerar-pdf.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\devweb\sistemas\painel\gerar-pdf.php on line 9
```

Este é código que eu escrevi:

```php
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('templateFinanceiro.php');
    $conteudo = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    require ('../vendor/autoload.php');

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mdpf->WriteHTML($conteudo);
    $mdpf->Output();
?>
```

Se alguém puder dar uma ajuda, eu agradeceria muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um erro de digitação, você escreveu primeiro **`$mpdf`** e depois **`$mdpf`**, trocou o `p` pelo `d`:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();    ---> Aqui esta M P D F
$mdpf->WriteHTML($conteudo); ---> Aqui esta M D P F
$mdpf->Output();
```

O certo seria:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($conteudo);
$mpdf->Output();
```

**Não é necessário `use`** para "instanciar", `use` é uma maneira de fazer um apelido para um namespace e classe, por exemplo:

Isto:

```
use Foo\Bar\Baz;
```

Seria equivalente:

```
use Foo\Bar\Baz as Baz;
```

Você pode usar `new \Mpdf\Mpdf` ou o apelido, não faz diferença, aliais se fosse erro de instanciar a mensagem de erro nem seria:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mdpf

O erro seria:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf' not found

Comment: arrumei aqui.. deu certo. muito obrigado!!